# Why does my MongoDB query use in-memory sort with a compound text index?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose, full-text-search

I am trying to query on MongoDB with a compound text index as below:

```
index : {name : 'text' , createdAt:'-1'}
```

That will create a compound index for the *name* and *createdAt* field, but when I try to query on those fields, it is using in-memory sorting although i defined the sorting order in a compound index.

`db.table.find({$text:{$search:"text"}}).sort({createdAt : -1})`

I checked MongoDB documentation, but I did not find any use case that matched with mine. I am expecting to remove in-memory sorting with text search with the above compound index.

Answer (score 0):

From the MongoDB documentation (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/indexes/index-types/index-text):

> ### Compound Text Indexes
>
> For a compound index that includes a text index
> key along with keys of other types, only the text index field
> determines whether the index references a document. The other keys do
> not determine whether the index references the documents.

Checking the `explain(true)` reveals that only the `text` component of the index is used.   Trying to be clever by switching the order of the compound index to:

```
db.foo.createIndex({createdAt:-1,name: "text"});
```

and issuing:

```
db.foo.find( { "createdAt":{$gt:0}, $text: { $search: "coffee" } } ).sort({createdAt:-1}).explain(true);
```

yields this error because a `createdAt` *equality* is required, not a range operator (`$gt`).

```
Proj: {}
 planner returned error :: caused by :: failed to use text index to satisfy $text query (if text index is compound, are equality predicates given for all prefix fields?)
```